# Why is my match formula giving inconsistent output?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using below formula to get the last value of each individual items in rows in a pivot table.

```
=HLOOKUP("Last Updated",$D$4:$D$293,MATCH(A5,$A$5:$A$293)+1)
```

The intention of using the match formula in this is to return the value of row. Its working fine up to 221 rows and then it is giving unusual row numbers in between and then at the end it starts working fine again.

I am unable to understand why the match formula is giving wrong output for only few rows.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) function assumes your array is sorted in ascending order:

> ```
> Match_type    Behavior
>
> 1 or omitted  MATCH finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value.  
>               The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in ascending order, 
>               for example: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE.
>
> 0             MATCH finds the first value that is exactly equal to lookup_value. 
>               The values in the lookup_array argument can be in any order.
>
> -1            MATCH finds the smallest value that is greater than or equal to lookup_value. 
>               The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in descending order, 
>               for example: TRUE, FALSE, Z-A, ...2, 1, 0, -1, -2, ..., and so on.
> ```

To get proper result use

`MATCH(A5,$A$5:$A$293,0)`

Comment: Juhasz, If I use 0 as third argument it given me the output from first exact match, whereas I want output from last exact match.

Comment: If I arrange my data in ascending order it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Match without the third argument. That will then default to true, which means that Match will return an approximate lookup, which has a high potential of producing a wrong result if the data is not sorted.

If you don't know about the TRUE or FALSE or `0` or `1` argument, have a read of https://teylyn.com/2015/01/15/vlookup-why-do-i-need-true-or-false/ which applies to Vlookup the same way as to Match.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the third argument that is working by default in my formula. But the issue is if I am mentioning 0 which means exact match the intention of doing this whole thing goes down the gutter since it takes the first exact match and I want it to take last exact match. Any idea how I can do that?